# Adding Event Listeners in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript and divs defined using CSS3 classes. I need to add event listener to specific class div but it is not getting bound to it.

e.g.:

```js
this._incrementEnabled = document.createElement('div');
this._incrementEnabled.className = this._incrementButtonProperties.enabledClass;
this.divElt.appendChild(this._incrementEnabled);

if (this.properties.incrementButtonConfig.enabled == null) {
    this.properties.incrementButtonConfig.enabled = false;
}

this.setIncrementEnabled(this.properties.incrementButtonConfig.enabled);

this._incrementEnabled.addEventListener('click', this._incrementButtonProperties.incrementSelectCallback, false);
```

and the CSS:

```css
.SchedMainCtrlIncrementBtn_En {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 240px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    width: 35px;
    height: 65px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url("../../../images/icons/IcnListAddRecipient_En.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: Not realy an awnser but try to use a framework. That makes your life much easyer. with jQuery it would be something like $(.classname).life('click', function to execute);

Comment: I do not want to use any Framework

Comment: what is `incrementSelectCallback` ?

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll( 'div.yourclass' );
for( var i=0; i < divs.length; i++ ){
    divs[ i ].addEventListener( 'eventname', callback, false );
}
```

EDIT:

From reading your code with this very long variable names I conclude that you want to do something like this:

```
this.element = document.createElement( 'div' );
this.element.className = 'someName';
this.parentElement.appendChild( this.element );
this.element.addEventListener( 'click', callback, false );
```

So if `this.parentElement` is not defined, or if `callback` is not defined it wont work. I do not know how you coded the class, but all used functions (`document.createElement`, `appendChild`, `addEventListener`) are native functions, so they work.

Comment: this is also not working..! Root cause is : divElt - unable to add listener to elt -  this._incrementEnabled.

Comment: hmmm.... To be honest, it is very difficult to find out where the mistake may be, but if you make a fiddle it would be more easy to find the bug.

Answer (score -2):

If possible try to use Jquery it will be simpler you can this `$('.class').click(function(){})`